# two criteria of lookup in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I want to lookup the value in `Columns C` of Sheets("MV_Backtest") s.t cell_i match `Columns A`, cell_j match `Columns B`, here is the code:

```
Sub Matrix()
  lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
  lastColumn = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 
  Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

  For i = 2 To lastRow
    For j = 3 To lastColumn
      cell_i = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 2)
      cell_j = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, j)
      Cells(i, j) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Lookup(1, 0 / (cell_i = 
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MV_Backtest").Columns("A:A")) * (cell_j = 
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MV_Backtest").Columns("B:B")), 
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MV_Backtest").Columns("C:C"))
    Next j
  Next i
End Sub
```

Note that each value in one column may not unique, but combining two values, it is unique.

It's ok in the Excel but there is something wrong here?

By the way, how  could I set `Cells(i, j) = 0` when neither of two conditions match.

Here is the Excel formula:

```
=LOOKUP(1,0/(I28=I20:I22)*(J28=J20:J22),K20:K22)
```

`cell_i`  is `I28`, `I20:I22` is `Columns A`, `cell_j`  is `J28`, `J20:J22` is `Columns B`, `K20:K22`  is `Columns C`.

Comment: can please post exact excel formula?...and for setting `Cells(i, j) = 0` you can simply use `If IsError(Cells(i, j)) Then Cells(i, j) = 0  End If`

Comment: @MaddyNikam pls see the update

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> (cell_i = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MV_Backtest").Columns("A:A")) * (cell_j = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MV_Backtest").Columns("B:B"))
> ```

While the above code looks correct for an Excel formula, it is not valid **VBA**. In Excel it generates and multiples two arrays, but you cannot generate an array like that in VBA (VBA does not allow array multiplication, array comparison, etc).

If you have a valid Excel formula, you can let Excel evaluate it then get the result. Two ways to do that:

1- Using `Application.Evaluate`:

```
Cells(i, j).value = Application.Evaluate("=Lookup(1,0/((" & cell_i & _
    "= MV_Backtest!A:A) * (" & cell_j &_
    "=MV_Backtest!B:B)), MV_Backtest!C:C)")
```

2- Using `.Formula`

```
Cells(i, j).Formula = "=Lookup(1,0/((" & _
  cell_i & "=MV_Backtest!A:A) * (" & _
  cell_j & "=MV_Backtest!B:B)), MV_Backtest!C:C)"
```

If you want after then to fix the value and remove the formula, you can:

```
Cells(i, j).Value = Cells(i, j).Value2
```

EDIT:

To set a cell to zero when no match exists, the usual way is the enclose the formula with `IFERROR(myformula, 0)`. Hence, for example:

```
 Cells(i, j).value = Application.Evaluate("=IFERROR(Lookup(1,0/((" & cell_i & _
    "= MV_Backtest!A:A) * (" & cell_j &_
    "=MV_Backtest!B:B)), MV_Backtest!C:C)), 0")
```

Or, you can check (in VBA) if the resulting value of the *initial formula* is an error code. i.e.

```
If IsError(Cells(i, j).Value) Then Cells(i, j).Value = 0
```

Comment: another problem is when there is no corresponding value, how to set as 0? Lookup may choose the last value.

Comment: pls see the update, so we can replace `" & _cell_i & "` by `cell_i ` in your code?

Comment: @A.Oreo not sure I understand, but if you mean you want to use the literal `I28` instead of a variable cell_i, then yes you can do that.

Comment: how to set 0 to the no corresponding value？

Comment: @A.Oreo see the additional edit. You basically enclose the initial formula with `IFERROR(myformula, 0)`.

Comment: @but if `Lookup` do not find the effective one, it may choose the last one in the array, so I think we can not use `IFERROR` here

Comment: @A.Oreo if not match occurs your formula *does* return an error code, according to my tests.

Comment: yes, so the non-matching value will not be zero, that isn't I want

Comment: @A.Oreo But then using Excel's `IFERROR` or VBA's `If IsError` will do the job.